# Accessing directly to a sub array of object it becomes an object of objetcs

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I need an array of objects to be passed to cavansJs. This array is an element of a more complex object passed from PHP to a JS script in this way

```
var active_alarms_data = JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode($activePriceAlarms,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);?>');
```

I tried also

```
var active_alarms_data = <?php echo json_encode($activePriceAlarms,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);?>;
```

This is the structure of the main object

[image]

The data for the chart is in the sub-array factory_made_avg_graph_prices_stats, printing on console.log the whole object, this field appears to be properly formatted as an array; it can be seen that is declared as an Array type with 104 elements each of which is indexed with a number from 0 to 103. Good is what I need!! But, when I refer directly to the array I got something of very strange

```
console.log("ELEMENT 0: " + active_alarms_data[i].graph.factory_made_avg_graph_prices_stats);
```

I got

[image]

and the chart remains empty probably just because the expected data format is different than the past one. Any suggestion?

Comment: don't add pictures of your code

Comment: You are looking at a string representation of each object in the array. If you remove the `"ELEMENT 0:"` and only log the array, then you'll see what you saw first

Comment: please remove "ELEMENT 0" from the console.log()

Comment: @Kunal Mukherjee i have not added pictures of code, that are data printed on console that couldnt' be copied. The code that i wrote is not a picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Nothing is wrong with your code.**

It's just the console log that is throwing you off. Accessing each of the elements as you are now will work fine. The reason you are seeing [object Object] is because when you concatenate (join with '+') something to a string in javascript, if it isn't a string, it will try to convert it to a string first.

You are looking at a string representation of each object in the array. If you remove the "ELEMENT 0:" and only log the array, then you'll see what you saw first. here's an example:

```js
const obj = { test: [{ foo: 'bar' }] }
console.log('ELEMENT 0: ' + obj.test)
console.log(obj.test)
```

Or, if you really needed to see "Element 0", you can use a comma, rather than direct concatenation:

```js
const obj = { test: [{ foo: 'bar' }] }
console.log('ELEMENT 0:', obj.test)
```

Comment: thank you ... so the problem of the empty chart was not a data format one!

Comment: @fede72bari Nope. You're good to go. It's just javascript trying to be helpful, but it isn't in this case. If you ever need more help, feel free to ask 

Answer (score -1):

Console like this :

```
console.log("ELEMENT 0: " , 
active_alarms_data[i].graph.factory_made_avg_graph_prices_stats);
```

Replace '+' to ',' in console